# SWI-prolog semweb library processing of URI

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, semweb

Being new to prolog I am reading existing code (as well as trying to write some code). Having some prior background in semweb I started to play with it and see something that is confusing me. Example assertion:

```
?- rdf_assert(ex:bob, rdf:type, foaf:'Person').
```

I also did find the following in the documentation:

```
Remember: Internally, all resources are atoms. The transformations
above are realised at compile-time using rules for goal_expansion/2
provided by the rdf_db library
```

Am I correct in assuming that somehow the library is treating the three URIs as atoms? I thought that the compiler would treat this as `module_name:predicate`, but that does not seem to be the case. If that is true, could you please provide a simple example on how this could be done in prolog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog is not a functional language.  This implies `2+3` does not *evaluate* to `5` and is just a term that gets *meaning* from the predicate that processes it.  Likewise, `ex:bob` is just a term that has no direct relations to modules or
predicates.  Only predicates such call/1 will interpret this as "call `bob` in the module `ex`".

Next to that, (SWI-)Prolog (most Prolog's, but not all) have *term expansion* that allows you to rewrite the term that is read before it is handed to the compiler.  That is used to rewrite the argument of `rdf/3`: each appearance of `prefix:local` is expanded to a full atom.  You can check that by using `listing/1` on predicates that call rdf/3 using the prefix notation.

See also [rdf_meta](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=rdf_prefixes%3Ardf_meta/1)